Loading and Inserting a table in csv format into a database
I am having trouble loading and inserting data from a table into a database I created. The table has a column that contains JSON data.
Could you help me understand what's wrong with the JSON data in that column and how I can fix it?
I am using the following Load statement to load the data:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/contracts_modified.csv' 
INTO TABLE contracts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS

However, I keep getting an error message that says:
Error Code: 3140. Invalid JSON text: "The document root must not be followed by other values." at position 3 in value for column 'contracts.version_history'.
This is a sample of the data I am trying to put in the table
_id,broker_id,created_by_id,customer_id,debt_collection,insurer_id,is_active,is_deductible_allowed,is_latest,no_offer,policy_generation,premiums,status,tender_id
62d55e41204b1f0007a561a3,JfC79Tw35xNwFWvxC,yo24GGhGDNz8iYJh9,62600dce306449000830fd47,FALSE,2wb3p5s2bw7aYjuiQ,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,"[{""insurance_sum"":500000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":612.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a56197"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":750000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":765.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a56198"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":1000000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":867.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a56199"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":1500000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":1275.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619a"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":2000000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":1693.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619b"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":2500000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":2091.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619c"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":3000000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":2479.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619d"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":4000000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":3297.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619e"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":5000000.0,""no_offer"":false,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":4080.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a5619f"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":7500000.0,""no_offer"":true,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":0.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a561a0"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":1.0E7,""no_offer"":true,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":0.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a561a1"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""},{""insurance_sum"":1.5E7,""no_offer"":true,""change_count"":0,""created_at"":null,""is_preliminary_allowed"":null,""remark"":null,""updated_by_company_id"":null,""is_approval_required"":true,""changes_metadata"":{},""deleted_at"":null,""premium"":0.0,""updated_at"":null,""deductible"":null,""created_by_company_id"":null,""rejection_reason"":null,""updated_by_id"":null,""_id"":""62d55e41204b1f0007a561a2"",""created_by_id"":null,""status"":""GENERATED""}]",GENERATED,62600e0cbeeb8700085c27b0

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It would be helpful if you provide your table structure and the csv file.
